# How to get parent class of a variable in java?

Tags: java

Lets say I have a class a, and a class b.

```
public class ClassA{
    int a;
    ClassB b = new ClassB();
}    
public class ClassB{
    int someInt;
    void someFunction(){
        //Here I want to access the variable a of the current ClassA.
    }
}`
```

The code is pretty self explanatory.
I can add the ClassA in the constructor, but i dont want to do that as ClassB will be created by the user.
so...perhaps some help here?

Comment: `ClassB` doesn't extend `ClassA` nor it has any reference to `ClassA`. What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: yes, but ClassA has the variable of ClassB. i want to access ClassB's parent...or whatever thats called

Comment: That's nothing, `ClassB b` doesn't know about `ClassA`. With your current design, there's no way from `b` to know anything about the object reference holding it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the 'parent' of a variable.

Comment: anyother way to achieve that?

Comment: non of your class extend each other so what are you defining parent and child in your code,??

Comment: sorry....what i meant is not parent....what i mean is, i want ClassB to know about ClassA who has a object of ClassB

Comment: There is no relation from `ClassB` to `ClassA` so the former does not know anything about the latter. The other way around though, `ClassA` knows its members and thus it knows it has a field referencing `ClassB`. That's all there is to deduct from this situation.

Comment: If you want a solution, you'll have to look into your design again and come up with an alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current design, `ClassB` knows nothing about the existance of `ClassA`. You would need to:

- Establish a direct association from `ClassB` to `ClassA`. Usually you do this through a field.
- Assigning the reference of `ClassA` into `ClassB`.

Here's a way to do it:

```
public class ClassA {
    int a;
    ClassB b = new ClassB(this);
}

public class ClassB {
    int someInt;
    ClassA classA;
    public ClassB(ClassA classA) {
        this.classA = classA;
    }
    void someFunction() {
        System.out.println(classA.a);
    }
}
```

Here's another way to do it:

```
public class ClassA {
    int a;
    ClassB b;
    public ClassA() {
        b = new ClassB();
        b.setClassA(this);
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    int someInt;
    ClassA classA;
    public ClassB() {
    }
    void setClassA(ClassA classA) {
        this.classA = classA;
    }
    void someFunction() {
        System.out.println(classA.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: as i said, i can add a constructor, but i dont wanna do that....is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @JohnBrac added another way. There are several ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your the code like below

```
 public class ClassA{
        int a;
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        public void m1(){
         b.someFunction(a)
    }
    }    
    public class ClassB{
        int someInt;
        void someFunction(int a){
            //Here I want to access the variable a of the current ClassA.
        }
    }`
```

Comment: It is because you fixed it :P

Answer (score 0):

If an instance of class B needs to reference an object that owns or otherwise refers to that instance of class B, the developer of B has got to implement a setter method (or provide a constructor argument) for the instance of A.  You have no way of forcing the developer of class B to do that, unless class B is supposed to fit into some framework that includes class A.  If that's the case, you can provide an interface that B must implement and through that interface force the implementation of a setter for an instance of A.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a member of `classA` then you will **have** to pass an instance of that class into your `someFunction` method, either via the constructor of `classB` or as a parameter of the method, i.e.

```
// Via constructor
public class ClassB {
    private ClassA a;
    public ClassB( ClassA a ) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public void someFunction() {
        System.out.println( a.a );
    }
}

// Via method
public class ClassB {
    public void someFunction( ClassA a ) {
        System.out.println( a.a );
    }
}
```

Or you could make the `a` member in `ClassA` a `static` but I don't think that's what you're after.